# App launched from firebase dynamic link disappears from recent apps

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links

Androidmanifest file:

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="**.**.com" android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:host="**.**.com" android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

I tried to launch the app with the short dynamic link.

It launches the app with no issues, but when I background the app, it disappears from the recent apps. Is this an expected behavior?